# What limit value I need set to stop my function?

Tags: javascript, progress-bar, progress

I'm trying to create a progress bar with a percentage text using only Javascript, but I don't know what value I need set in the function to limit the incrementation. The bar and the text keep increasing.
Need create 4 skills bar with 30% / 50% / 70% and 90%.

Help, plz! Accept any suggestions!
Here is my code.

```
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar"></div>
        <p value="30" class="text">30</p>
    </div>

  <script>
    function update() { 
      let element = document.querySelector(".progress-bar");    
      let counter = document.querySelector(".text");
      var width = 1; 
      var identity = setInterval(scene, 10); 
      function scene() { 
        if (width >= counter.value) { 
          clearInterval(identity); 
        } else { 
          width++;  
          element.style.width = width + '%';  
          counter.innerHTML = width * 1  + '%'; 
        } 
      } 
    } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am following the issue you are experiencing. I see your code can be improved and would solve some problems. Here what I suggest:

```
function update() { 
  let element = document.querySelector(".progress-bar");    
  let counter = document.querySelector(".text");
  let width = 1; 
  setTimeout(scene, 1); 
  function scene() { 
    if (width < 100) {
      width++;  
      element.style.width = width + '%';  
      counter.innerHTML = width * 1  + '%'; 
      setTimeout(scene, 1); 
    } else {
      //Complete action here
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you @bipsa but what I'm saying is that I need to use this function for 4 more progress bars, for example: the progress bar "Food" needs to fill up to 40%, the progress bar "Cleaning" needs to fill up to 70%, the progress bar "Car" needs to fill up to 100%, you know?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow! Below you can see a working example of your code with minimal changes. I just defined that when the percenteage comes up to 100, it clears the interval on the page.

```js
function update() {
  let element = document.querySelector(".progress-bar");
  let counter = document.querySelector(".text");
  var percenteage = 0;
  var identity = setInterval(scene, 50);

  function scene() {
    if (percenteage < 100) {
      percenteage++;
      element.style.width = percenteage + '%';
      counter.innerHTML = percenteage + ' %';

    } else {
      clearInterval(identity);
      console.log("Cleared!");
    }
  }
}

update();
```

```css
.progress-bar {
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar"></div>
  <p value="30" class="text">30</p>
</div>
```